# Eclipse/Ant - Environment variable not recognized

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, environment-variables

I have an Ant script which when run via terminal - it recognizes all environment variables (as expected). However when i run the very same script from eclipse the environment variable is not recognized.

I have changed the version of Ant which eclipse should use (so instead of the default and i am using system ant) but to no avail.

example:

```
Terminal:
[copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Apache\tomcat\lib

Eclipse:
[copy] Copying 1 file to C:\eclipse\workspace\<project>\${env.TOMCAT_HOME}\lib
```

It is so frustrating that Eclipse fails with these type of stuff.

Comment: Are you using the ant "builder" in eclipse? If so, I believe one of the tabs on that builder allows you to define environment variables, perhaps you could define the TOMCAT_HOME variable there. I think you could also define that variable globally w/in eclipse which might also do the trick.

Comment: This is because Eclipse does not recognise environment variables for its Ant shells. What you can do is you can go to *Run As > Ant Build... > Environment* and add the variables you need.